# pandas reordering rows in df

Tags: pandas, rows

I'm having an issue with reordering rows in my df1:

```
Name value1  value2 ...
ABC  1       3
ADC  2       3
IJK  3       4
XYZ  0       5
```

I want the result only show the row with name XYZ and ABC:

```
Name value1  value2 ...
XYZ  0       5
ABC  1       3
```

I tried:

`df1 = df1[df1['Name'].str.contains('XYZ'||'ABC')]` and

`df1 = df1[df1['Name'].isin(['XYZ','ABC'])]`

but it returns blank.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the reason why `isin` not work, it should contain the withe blank

And after fixed your `str.contains`

```
df[df['Name'].str.contains('XYZ|ABC')]
Out[619]: 
  Name  value1  value2
0  ABC       1       3
3  XYZ       0       5
```

Reorder

```
df[df['Name'].str.contains('XYZ|ABC')][::-1]
Out[620]: 
  Name  value1  value2
3  XYZ       0       5
0  ABC       1       3
```

Comment: Oops, I did not see this, when I wrote my answer.

Comment: Just mention that OP needs `df.Name = df.Name.str.strip()` for `isin` to work.

Comment: Is there a way I can reorder the rows however I want?

Comment: @TylerNG How do you want to reorder them? That's somewhat of a different question, but if you want to _sort_, then use `df.sort_values('Names', ascending=False)`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
In [10]: lst = ['XYZ','ABC']

In [11]: d = {x:i for i,x in enumerate(lst)}

In [12]: d
Out[12]: {'ABC': 1, 'XYZ': 0}

In [13]: df.assign(x=df.Name.map(d)).sort_values('x').drop('x',1).query("Name in @lst")
Out[13]:
  Name  value1  value2
3  XYZ       0       5
0  ABC       1       3
```